# SQL/Postgres join where clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, where-clause

I have 2 tables observations & study.
Study contains the name of the study(study), id of each object in the study and the start_date & end_date

Observations contains the id, date (date of observation), and the observation (column name 'comment')

I want to  get every id from study  that matches a study name (select id from study where study = "ST009")
Then I want to get every observation from observations that match the id from study between 2 dates (dates can be any 2 dates, not limited to start_date and end_date)

Study Table:

```
study   id   start_date   end_date
ST0009  A    2019-01-01   2019-02-15
ST0009  B    2019-01-01   2019-02-15
ST0009  C    2019-01-01   2019-02-15
ST0010  D    2019-01-10   2019-02-20
ST0010  D    2019-01-10   2019-02-10
```

Observation table

```
date       id  comments
2019-01-02 A   Cracks on edges
2019-01-02 B   Soft center
2019-01-10 A   Cracks moving to the center
2019-01-11 D   Curled edges 
2019-01-12 A   Edges separating from body
2019-01-15 D   Curled edges cracking
2019-01-25 B   Center becoming solid
```

Restults:

```
ID  observations.date observations.comment
A   2019-01-02       Cracks on edges
A   2019-01-10       Cracks moving to the center
A   2019-01-12       Edges separating from body
B   2019-01-02       Soft center
B   2019-01-25       Center becoming solid
C
```

Hopefully, this makes sense

Comment: `SELECT s.id, o.date, o.comment FROM studies s 
LEFT JOIN observations o ON s.id = o.id
ORDER BY s.id`

How's this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just join the tables and apply the filters in the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT s.*
       FROM observation o
            INNER JOIN study s
                       ON s.id = o.id
       WHERE s.study = 'ST009'
             AND o.date >= '$from'
             AND o.date < '$to';
```

`$from` and `$to` are your any two dates.

Comment: Thanks, I was not sure which order to put things in.